# Can't insert files in other inputs

Tags: plugins, php, javascript

I'm trying to allow multiple images to be uploaded to the media library where I can then take the URL of the image and insert it into a custom page on the website but for some reason, when I click on the other input buttons, it doesn't work and doesn't display the media library upload dropdown and selects the first inputs text field. I can't figure out why I can't use the other inputs and upload multiple images at once.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

This is the JS:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#upload_image_button').click(function() {
    formfield = jQuery('#upload_image').attr('name');
    tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&TB_iframe=true');
    return false;
    });

    window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
    imgurl = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');
    jQuery('#upload_image').val(imgurl);
    tb_remove();
    }

    });
    </script>
```

This is the input fields form:

```
<tr valign="top">
        <td>Upload Ad for Position 1</td>
        <td><label for="upload_image">
            <input id="upload_image" type="text" size="36" name="upload_ad1_doc" value="<?php echo $gearimage; ?>" />
            <input id="upload_image_button" type="button" value="Upload Image" />
            <br />Enter an URL or upload an image for the ad.
            </label>
        </td>
    </tr><br /><br />
    <tr valign="top">
        <td>Upload Ad for Position 2</td>
        <td><label for="upload_image">
            <input id="upload_image" type="text" size="36" name="upload_ad2_doc" value="<?php echo $gearimage; ?>" />
            <input id="upload_image_button" type="button" value="Upload Image" />
            <br />Enter an URL or upload an image for the ad.
            </label>
        </td>
    </tr><br /><br />
    <tr valign="top">
        <td>Upload Ad for Position 3</td>
        <td><label for="upload_image">
            <input id="upload_image" type="text" size="36" name="upload_ad3_doc" value="<?php echo $gearimage; ?>" />
            <input id="upload_image_button" type="button" value="Upload Image" />
            <br />Enter an URL or upload an image for the ad.
            </label>
        </td>
    </tr>

function wp_gear_manager_admin_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}

function wp_gear_manager_admin_styles() {
wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');
}

add_action('admin_print_scripts', 'wp_gear_manager_admin_scripts');
add_action('admin_print_styles', 'wp_gear_manager_admin_styles');
```

Comment: I changed the name attribute on the inputs to see if it would work or not, otherwise they are all named 'image_upload'

Answer (score 0):

You have three input elements with `id="upload_image"` and three with `id="upload_image_button"`. So jQuery is working with first elements only.

Remember, `id` means `identity`.